# Set auto constraints in such a way that it displays same in all devices in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a register form in ios swift in which i have applied auto constraints for iphone 7plus. but i am not getting same in all devices. how can i do it for 5s, 6s plus and 7s plus device. looks good in 6s plus and 7s plus but not in 5s

below screenshot for iphone 5s

[image: iphone 5s]

screenshot of what i have tried below

[image: what i tried]

Comment: Could you explain more how the layout looks in devices you mentioned? please attach any screenshot being looked improperly.

Comment: How to in constraints is a matter of learning them first , no answer will cover it

Answer (score 2):

**For ProfileImage**

- set Horizontally in Container
- set Width and Height of image
- set Top constraint

**For ALL TextFields**

- place all fields in the vertical StackView
- Set Stackview DISTRIBUTION property to FILL EQUALLY
- set Stack view leading, trailing constraint
- set Stackview vertical constraint in Container
- set Height for Stackview

**For NEXT BUTTON**

- set Leading, Trailing constraint and Height constraint
- set Top constraint to Stackiew

**For Already You have an ACCOUNT**

- set Leading, Trailing constraint and Height constraint
- set Bottom constraint to View

Comment: **For ALL TextFields** `set Height for Stackview` is not a good approach in all devices for stretching purposes  , you need to hook top and bottom to near by elements ,  you need to think proportionally  , same for profile image static w/h , also buttons / labels have an intrinsic content size no need for height

Comment: Ok perfect ... Thanks for your great guidance. I would like to ask one thing, if suppose there are 2 fields in a Stackview and its Constraints are leading, trailing,  top, and bottom then the text field size will grow Automatically... and then text field not looks so good... hope you get my point...? so in this case, what constraints are suitable?